# how to get the correct number of followers without going to another line

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url="https://manifest.in.ua/rt/?order_type=_subscribercount&order=DESC"

r = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser' )

mnflist=(soup.find('table', class_='rating-table bg-white w-full border-collapse overflow-hidden'))

chn_list=(mnflist.findAll('a', class_='rating-table__channel-name underline hover_no-underline inline-block align-middle font-manrope'))

subs=(mnflist.findAll('td', class_='text-left min font-manrope'))

t=20



for g in range(5,len(chn_list)):
    print(chn_list[g].text,end=',')
    print(subs[t+0].text,end=',')#with this me need help
    print(subs[t+1].text,end=',')
    print(subs[t+2].text,end=',')
    print(subs[t+3].text)
    t+=4
```

How can I print inline without creating a newline?

Answer (score 0):

To print inline, you can use a carriage return `\r` to the `end=` parameter:

```py
print(i, end="\r")
```